# With how many spark nodes should I use Mesos or Yarn?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, mesos

I currently run a cluster with 4 spark nodes and 1 solr node. I want to expand the cluster quickly to 20 nodes and afterwards around 100. I am just not sure at what cluster size it would make sense to use Mesos or Yarn? Does it make sense to add Yarn or Mesos when I have less then 100 nodes?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mesos and YARN can scale upto thousands of nodes without any issue.

It is the the workload that decides what to be used, if your workload has jobs/tasks related to spark or hadoop only, YARN would be a better choice, else if you have Docker containers or something else to run then Mesos would be a better choice.

There are many other advantages and disadvantages using Mesos, please find them  in the comparison [here](https://www.quora.com/How-does-YARN-compare-to-Mesos).

Spark standalone cluster will provide almost all the same features as the other cluster managers if you are only running Spark.

If you would like to run Spark alongside other applications, or to use richer resource scheduling capabilities (e.g. queues), both YARN and Mesos provide these features. Of these, YARN will likely be preinstalled in many Hadoop distributions.

If you have less than 100 nodes and you are not going to run any other applications alongside spark then spark standalone cluster would be a better choice as you would not be overkilling.

It again depends on the capabilities that you would like to use like the queues or schedulers like Fair scheduler then YARN/Mesos would make sense.
(To use these features or not to use them depends on what you do with the spark cluster, workload and how busy your cluster is.)

Comment: Interacting with cassandra is fine, it doesn't make a difference with any of the above clusters.

Comment: thanks. If I had 16 spark nodes which are also in the same cluster with cassandra and also need to do read and write to cassandra. I am currently using spark standalone with python. I would like to increase the performance of my spark app. But do I really need Yarn and what would be the benefits of the cluster mode?

Comment: Having YARN to schedule your tasks would depend on how busy your cluster would be, if your cluster is going to be very busy and would be handling tens of jobs per second then YARN would be beneficial because of its advanced queuing and scheduling capabilities when compared to the spark standalone cluster manager.

Comment: Having a Cassandra cluster would also not change any of these behaviors except it can save you network traffic if you can get the nearest contact point for the spark executor(Just like data locality).

Comment: When you submit your application in cluster mode all you job related files would be copied on to one of the machines on the cluster which would then submit the job on your behalf, if you submit the application in client mode the machine from which the job is being submitted would be taking care of driver related activities. This means that the machine from which the job has been submitted cannot go offline, whereas in cluster mode the machine from which the job has been submitted can go offline.